# I2C communication between LTC6804-1 and STM32 Nuclue F446RE

Tags: stm32, i2c, serial-communication, adc

I am trying to build a small battery monitoring system using LTC 6804-1 IC which will send the cell voltages over I2C to my STM32 Nucleo board. I have read and understood I2C and how to use the HAL APIs for communication. However, I am not able to understand anything about the communication from the datasheet of LTC 6804-1. https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/680412fc.pdf       I was looking for the slave address it sends data to and also the length of data. But I can see configuring some data registers which is bit of confusing. At point I do not know where to even start? Or is it actually easy that I have to connect wires and it starts?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The LTC6804 is not using I2C for communication, it's using SPI. It can host I2C communication to a slave device. Reread the data sheet thoroughly. Although I must agree, the manual is not really written very well, or at least there could be a lot more info, not only on how to get started...